# save Matlab output to file, instead of displaying on screen

Tags: matlab, save, screen

I use some optimization function and it displays results of iteration steps to the screen. How can I save the iteration results to file, instead of displaying them on the screen?

I referred to fprintf but it doesn't work in my case. Also diary does not work, because I do not want to display on screen.

Many thanks.

Comment: When you say display it : text ? image ? Matrix ?

Comment: version  predcorr  gam  expon  scale_data
    NT      1      0.000   1        0    
it pstep dstep pinfeas dinfeas  gap      prim-obj      dual-obj    cputime
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 0|0.000|0.000|1.6e+00|5.2e+00|1.8e+06| 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00| 0:0:00| chol  1  1

Comment: not simple single format, but with mixture of text, lines, and number vectors.

Comment: @user3046721: Which lines of code produce the output? Please provide a pice of code that demonstrates why diary did not work. I assume this can easily be adapted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple thing,

create a logFile. Start your function with :

```
fid = fopen(logFile,'w+');
```

When you want to display something you can do :

```
fprintf(fid,'This is my result %d.\n',100); % Will print in the file
fprintf('This is my result %d.\n',100); % Will print on screen
```

And remember at the end of your function to close it :

```
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: But how can I store the output as a variable and pass it to fprintf?

Comment: Can you provide some code ? I can't help you without what you have already done sorry.

Comment: Yes. I am using CVX (http://cvxr.com/cvx/). And the code is: cvx_begin
    variable beta(d)
    minimize((X*beta-y)'*(X*beta-y) + Lambda1*norm(beta,1))
cvx_end                It will print result of each iteration

Comment: I have never work with that before. But If you look in cvx\sdpt3\Solver and cvx\sdpt3\HSDSolver you have 2 main function that contain all the printf. You need to modify all those print to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use evalc when you call your function to capture its output.

```
T = evalc('string to evaluate')
```

This will capture all the output strings which would normally be printed in the command window. You can then write T to a file.